# click event not firing on a bootstrap drop down menu in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dropdown menu for a button using jquery and bootstrap but the menu closes as soon as I click on it. There's a textbox inside that button that I need to enter text into.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Hyperlink"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu input-append" id = "hyperlink-menu">
                <input class="span2" placeholder="URL" type="text" data-edit="createLink"/>             
                <button class="btn" type="button">Add</button>
            </div>
```

Here's the Javascript part of it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hyperlink-menu').click(function(e) {
        alert("Asd");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

I am trying to prevent the menu from closing when someone types into the textbox. This is how the fiddle should look like(Except other buttons ofcourse)

[image]

That alert box is not firing! I know this question is sort of redundant but I got the document.ready idea after going through other similar questions! None of them seem to be working!

I tried creating a fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/2ca9hh7g/) but it's really very messed up....

Comment: Do you want to catch the opening of the menu ?

Comment: You given click on `hyperlink-menu` instead give on`.btn` check http://jsfiddle.net/2ca9hh7g/2/

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2ca9hh7g/13/) what you were after?

Comment: When someone clicks on that link button a menu popsup which has a textbox in it. When someone tries to type into that menu, it closes automatically. I want to prevent that!

Comment: The div you are targeting is empty and there is nothing to click. Set the click on the div as Ketan says. Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6pc9fu9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the click on span2 solved my problem.